# putty can't connect to local network machine

Tags: ssh, putty, vagrant

My problem i a little bit strange. I have a windows 7 machine. I can connect to remote machines with putty (ssh). But I can't connect to local network machines.

If I try to connect to local machines with an other PC than mine, it's fine.

I noticed this problem after installing vagrant on my machine.

Have you got any idea about this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Were you able to `ping` those local machines from your Win7?

Comment: yes I can. I noticed also that when I call web pages hosted in these machines or open FTP connection, the first connection is very slow. After that, it seems to be normal. But ssh connection still don't work.